# error while compiling with matlab mex

Tags: matlab, mex, ld-preload

I am try to compile using matlab mex, but i keep receiving this error:

```
Warning: You are using gcc version "5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.2.3".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

In file included from descriptor.h:4:0,
                 from calc_shot.cpp:11:
mesh.h: In function ‘double magnitude(const vec3d<T>&)’:
mesh.h:106:9: error: ‘sqrt’ is not a member of ‘std’
  return std::sqrt((v1.x*v1.x) + (v1.y*v1.y) + (v1.z*v1.z));
         ^
In file included from calc_shot.cpp:11:0:
descriptor.h: At global scope:
descriptor.h:7:57: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 class invalid_mesh_descriptor : public std::logic_error {
                                                         ^
descriptor.h: In constructor ‘invalid_mesh_descriptor::invalid_mesh_descriptor()’:
descriptor.h:9:57: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
    explicit invalid_mesh_descriptor() : std::logic_error("Exception invalid_mesh_descriptor caught.") {}
                                                         ^
descriptor.h:9:57: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
descriptor.h: In constructor ‘invalid_mesh_descriptor::invalid_mesh_descriptor(const string&)’:
descriptor.h:10:70: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
    invalid_mesh_descriptor(const std::string& msg) : std::logic_error("Exception invalid_mesh_descriptor caught: "+msg) {}
                                                                      ^
descriptor.h:10:70: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
descriptor.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const vec_descriptor<T>&)’:
descriptor.h:123:45: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const char [2]’)
       for (size_t k=1; k < d.size(); ++k) s << " " << d(k);
                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from descriptor.h:5,
                 from calc_shot.cpp:11:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:5172:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:5172:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from calc_shot.cpp:11:0:
descriptor.h:123:48: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘const char [2]’
       for (size_t k=1; k < d.size(); ++k) s << " " << d(k);
                                                ^

    mex: compile of ' "calc_shot.cpp"' failed.
```

i used to compile this code with LD_PRELOAD but at the moment i do not remember the argument, how can i solve?

Comment: I have noticed that all compilers does not include headers the same way. You may have to include some extra headers. The first one for example, `mesh.h:106:9: error: ‘sqrt’ is not a member of ‘std’`. The reason may actually be that you need to `#include <cmath>`. There might be other issue like this as well, but I am not sure.

Comment: Another example is `descriptor.h:123:45: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const char [2]’)`. This one likely need `#include <string>`

Comment: the code is fine, i used to compie it using the right parameters but i can't remember them

Comment: Well, obviously there are missing headers in the code. The evidence is all over the post. I have no idea how you did to get the headers into the code the last time, but they are not there now. You may miss some file when compiling the code, or there may be something else. I suggest trying to explain the problem more thoroughly and show what you did to get these errors.

Answer (score 1):

solution:

```
mex -v calc_shot.cpp shot_descriptor.cpp -DUSE_FLANN -I"C:\Program Files\flann\include" -I/usr/include/eigen3
```

using this command the programs works like a charm